# What's the best life advice you would give to a child in Hex Speak?

Tags: word-property, puzzle-creation, letters, letter-sequence, word-sequence

This puzzle involves coming up with a sentence using any of following:

- characters: **ABCDEF** (+5 points)
- numbers: **0123456789** (+3 points)
- numbers disguised as letters: **OILSTRG** (0,1,1,5,7,12,6)  (+3 points)
- rebuses: "d" as "the", "o" as "oh", "2" as "-to/-too/to-", "4" as "for-/-for", "8" as "-ate/ate",  (+10 points)

A sentence encompassing the golden rule earns an extra 100 points (but don't try *too* hard). Bonus points can also be earned for an intelligent sentence or phrase with good advice regarding:

- 50 points: money, work, jobs (e.g. "money is the root of all evil", but in hex)
- 40 points: "life", life goals or life purpose, spirituality
- 30 points: effort, practice
- 20 points: people, friends, romance
- 10 points: education

X-factor: Up to 100 points for something that is unexpected, novel, funny, or entertaining! Existing mantras converted to hex could also be worth a lot!

Upvotes: Each upvote is worth 110 points!

**The maximum length for a suggestion is 35 characters. Only the highest scoring suggestion in an answer will count.** Any answers derived from other user's answers (even not the second user's highest scoring ones) will be disqualified.

This question will stay open for 7 to 10 days, and I will be placing a bounty on it as well (when eligible).

Some more background, from Wikipedia:

> Hexspeak, like leetspeak, is a novelty form of variant English spelling using the hexadecimal digits. ... Hexadecimal notation represents numbers using the 16 digits 0123456789ABCDEF. Using only the letters ABCDEF it is possible to spell several words... Further words can be made by treating some of the decimal numbers as letters - the digit "0" can represent the letter "O", and "1" can represent the letters "I" or "L". Less commonly, "5" can represent "S", "7" represent "T", "12" represent "R" and "6" or "9" can represent "G" or "g", respectively. Numbers such as 2, 4 or 8 can be used in a manner similar to leet or rebuses; e.g. the word "defecate" can be expressed either as DEFECA7E or DEFEC8.

Here's a list of over 2000 hex words that will help (no rebuses though), though there are other lists on the net with more! Remember "d" is "the"!
https://www.litscape.com/word_tools/contains_only.php

> a d or so re os to as at la it is el sea ag sat tea rot
>   ail roe air ais tar ale rat do ors ore toe oil sot oat are oar lot ars
>   art sol lit lie ad ate let lea tie its sit sir ire id go eta era els
>   set eat ear ab age sate toil sari salt sale sail ago tars aid sag sad
>   rots rote taro rose role roil roes tare toes ails tale rod rite rise
>   airs tail riot rile rig riel rid rial rest red real tag rats rate tad
>   tsar rail rag stir ales star ores aloe trio oral sort also olea old
>   alto oils sore soli ode oats sole tire ares oars soil aril lots loti
>   sod tile soar lost lose lore arts ties log lite slot list lire lira
>   lies lier ado lid sloe slit liar lets slat lest leg led leas lear site
>   late last lari lair lag lad tier sire ads isle tore ires silt iota
>   ilea ids ide silo got gos seta get gel gas gal etas teas eros erg eras
>   sera seat sear ego eats seal east ears earl tear dot dos doe teal die
>   be grit arise bat lotis road roast loser arils rites loris rob rode
>   trod trios riots aisle riles rods roils roist lores tries bet rigs
>   arid roles alb aids sac riels lord rids ride trial rib logs aide sage
>   rials lode said resit bit resat reoil sard trail ages relit arc fa lob
>   odes gad ergs boa ergo gait gale load egos told litre toils liter
>   toile gals of ef litas gaol toga toed edit reds redo earls gate toad
>   gear tires bar aster dots liras ogle gels dote bra dose tiles tiler
>   gets ogre dors astir lied dolt lids dole seral oiler gilt reast dog
>   does tiers altos doer tied girl tide gist setal tic sic liars tesla
>   side tears teals reals taser dirt alter legs dire tarsi taros oleas
>   least abs tares orals tales ace glia tails car tags sitar lead dig
>   diet later laser dies read laris slate dial ratio rates sled orate
>   goal slid deli goat lard lairs slier cat tab laid lags deil god lads
>   raise lade slog store cis stole rails sob goer orb lab soda goes raid
>   islet aloes steal rags ired dear irate deal iotas stare rage stale
>   stair date dart if dare alert stag gore idol solar sold cot arose idle
>   ides ice act idea tilde coil ideal cole colt bale ices cog icer solid
>   ideas core grits idler soled race grist cost griot cod grid cots great
>   grate idles stab grail radio gores idols dab coat dalet stage dares
>   ifs darts staid dater acre dates deair rages coal deals dealt clot
>   dears gold stead orca raids orbs bait acts goers labs lace gods adios
>   cite celt lades slob cats lager deils deist bail gob goats lards slide
>   cast large goals delta case goad cart rated cars largo tabs taco adore
>   alder slab dials sited gloat lased aces bag diets care reads digs
>   leads sired talc glare legit glad cad dirts albs bad sidle oldie older
>   tics tidal tides base bris doers brie doest tiger cola gird doge lice
>   brat dogs gild bras doles oiled dolts ogres tiled bars ogles bots
>   doter dotes ogler bore geld tired drag gears dreg sect able gator
>   dries gates aft droit aside bolt abet toads gaols bole oft ref togas
>   edits boil efs bog boat gales boas elf gaits scot loads bare regal
>   boar blot odist regas gab scat scar trade fro blat sated relog aged
>   lobe lobs bits agile bite aglet tread resod far retag loci triad sager
>   fat lodes bios bile ribs for rice big aider rides arcs lords bid aides
>   bias foe bets tried beta best oared riled ailed belt beg triod oaf
>   rodes fir bed robs aired rited robe beat bear bats fit tsadi roads
>   stoic tories gobs biota citer lodge cites clad baste orbit clag labor
>   goads slice litres bird clast clear abore slater cleat ratios boats
>   glob alters clod betas sterol abets dibs dice react clog baits baser
>   bode close bald broil toiler glide clots glib liters cab beats alerts
>   oafs glade dirge begs staler ileac sift telco disc abort ocrea coals
>   oscar bogs basil coast girds ostler bide bade coati coats cob biter
>   boils bold octal serial doges serf cads left gilds coda serail code
>   cage bites acres sortie cods coed bales belts serac rebit afro bead
>   blare geoid cogs lobes oleic drab coils blast self colas drags cold
>   sortal dregs drib trails absit bolts bids talcs gated colts coral
>   icers cord lorate tribe garb ebola tailor iced blats leaf aced cores
>   abler acers blear card bleat costa besot grids acter refs bares bores
>   cares caret ogled bled blest gabs score trials bloat crag relast scare
>   races bard crate relic scale grads relist actor satire grade tacos
>   crest fret grab baler salter raft fad reoils resail fort fail cries
>   carol fair gored lobar bags sailor dabs sailer resoil tilers fare fore
>   retail lift trace fast bears brad carts loiter fate brag lories fats
>   fear fora caste feat raged fed rices safe life table felt brail ridge
>   feta blog loaf rife foil rift beast sabre sable saber fog foes blots
>   golds acid debt bates fig ascot soft sofa cater foal file brats loft
>   boars cedi floe sober bred beds fire bails alef robes libre liber
>   certs orates flit firs laces boast fist degas fits flea lacer flat
>   oilers daters flare bated roadie flag flats beads fleas fled flier
>   flies flirt first fires flits float beard robed filet rioted files
>   floes flog triods flora filer triode aigret roiled foals begot aisled
>   figs bides bidet aiglet bigot rifts aiders bilge fib fogs fetor rifle
>   foils foist logic fetas fold fetal triage folia feral felts feds safer
>   riced feats feast fears fates lofts arced biogs triads sagier birds
>   retold fares retags treads aglets blade resold sailed lobed false
>   fairs fails fads forte trades forts resaid fade frail salted relogs
>   loafs frets bloc reload scab blogs fries board loader scald frog abide
>   toiled bodes bogie relaid frost bolds listed gable scold bored bards
>   tirade bared ligate gaiter ligase elogia scrag lifts galore egoist
>   oglers refit editor lifes gaoler edict lifer brads barge redial after
>   brags braid tildes bread gaslit bride tigers driest dribs gators afros
>   abode tierod gelato drabs dotier broad oldest cabs doters oldies cadet
>   cadre dorsal rebid gift lefts cages aloft leafs rebag tailed cards
>   serif cared afire dobra based distal disco sidler bagel direst lasted
>   silted cargo glares adroit dilate adores largos larges cased dicot
>   dices tabid dicer laired gloats dialer alders slated globe detail
>   globs desilt desalt strode derail deltas lagers goalie aldose delist
>   cedar ladies delf raised slider deft adobe adlib railed cedis soared
>   decor stride decal stored sodic goiter debts goitre softa debit debar
>   golf deairs deaf flair daft rafts orated cider soiled cigar cried
>   stolid baled crib grabs grace radios laced credo cited clade stogie
>   clags crags acids grails ordeal clods grates gratis crab greats solder
>   clogs coaid raced stared griots staled stager corgi cored cords idlest
>   rabid acted cobs idlers acrid coder balds colds codes ideals coeds
>   sorted garbs coif corals sorbet rabies cobra stable staged coarse
>   corset coarb cosier costal coaler grief closet closer costar grated
>   clef isobar crabs cleats clears orbits baiter solace claret racist
>   graft crates labors citers grades cresol cribs lacers crista lacier
>   actors golfs gofer social defat delfs delft caters slicer strobe
>   balers castor dialog reacts castle caster glides digest cartel tables
>   glider carols carob caries glared glades dirges carets girdle dogear
>   carbs dogsat abseil oracle gilder dogsit calf gifts caged cafe rebait
>   badge dosage cadge geoids dotage reboil aborts telcos recast colter
>   libate broils geodal draft sector drift barite breast recoal recoat
>   braise brails ablest aortic recoil rectal seadog eclair gaoled bract
>   brace scrota barf barest gaited scoria boric erotic boreal borate
>   bolter sclera regild boiler escort frogs scaler bocal boater relics
>   relict oecist face fried blocs fact ageold bloats traces lobate bleats
>   fades forge blares albite octals locate biters bistro fared albeit
>   fated biotas oblate forb oblast riblet ribose folds fetid fogas fibs
>   tribal tribes foci field betoil bestir besort fobs filed flogs fired
>   flab basic flags baster cable befit reblog tragic clades floret gerbil
>   rebids falser falter baited itself giblet carted crated farce rebags
>   delict focal cagier credit tabled bilges coders deltic foetal sliced
>   bolide calfs faster abides rifles bailed bedlar casted coedit basted
>   croft calif folate albedo clefs cleft ridges dacite softie stifle
>   fecal softer coifs bolted bagels coiled folic broads dicers globes
>   beards barges braids dicots biased barfs colder forbs force fetors
>   sacred bedirt fiber gobies goblet trifle sabred forest afters fibre
>   sabled abider edicts resift closed borage bodies fortes boards cebid
>   foster strife scried fiesta blades adsorb debars coaled direct lifers
>   sifter debits debris lifter cedars debtor sorbed bogies scored filets
>   filter breads disbar graces batoid blared airbed bridal sodger ceroid
>   gabler gables boiled scarf decals gaelic scared bigots loafer doable
>   brides dobras refits fable docile scaled flabs decart cosied decors
>   ciders faces flares facet cadets facie oblige garble lodger cigars
>   lodges redact cargos garlic traced adlibs defog logics fliers bedsit
>   reclog bridle coated flirts facts adobes boated cafes bolder cradle
>   reclad brief floats balder craft bidets abodes cabler decaf lofted
>   sodalite lodestar defats sorbic loafed delators delfts asteroid lifted
>   diastole adrift dilaters dilators cobras cobalt sifted leotards coarbs
>   bilged afield seraglio isolated drafts drifts barged seafog scribe
>   bisect griefs grafts faced graced dafter golfer failed fardel fasted
>   gofers bocals fedora globed bodega gloaters fields flared carobs
>   foaled foetid geodic rifted fogies rifled foiled braces bracts bridge
>   tailored folder garbed forage reflag reflog forges refold forget
>   gabled cables rafted badger decarb golfed stodgier farces badges
>   coalites sortable godliest godetias coaliser dogstail storable felsic
>   laborist fiasco orbitals codger fibers fibres bodice crafts cebids
>   fiscal gifted trilobes sectoral coaliest digestor costlier recitals
>   crofts defogs foible braced libators cloister ergatoid erotical bardic
>   briefs calorist fables steroidal defrag calorise calories loricate
>   califs befits forces forged facets facies factor bloaters fresco
>   articles fridge clefts frolic societal cabled coalised catelogs
>   bedrails obligate frailest trilobed cordials decrials bristled
>   refloats forestal obligers forced cordates forbid deorbits bifold
>   dialects foliates loricates oilbased disabler trefoils redcoats
>   broadest driblets orgastic barfed ergatoids scleroid estradiol
>   rabidest floatier floaters fabled tabloids carotids articled blastoid
>   radicels radicles radicose ragbolts citadels fibred fidget glaciers
>   frigates calibers iceboats forelaid escargot gaolbird foliated
>   deflator brigades foliages boracite aerobics obstacle fabric calorised
>   disgrace dogcarts loricated decalogs obligates froglets isograft
>   globated abridges forestial cabriole bisector algebroid filberts
>   decabits gadflies cefrotil obligated cabrioles catbirds fibrates
>   sociable cabriolet forecast deflators fasciole fireboat trifocal
>   barcodes lifeboat firebolt gaolbirds foliaged dislocate gasfield
>   gasfired botflies barflies firedogs alfresco boracites baldrics
>   focalise carbides brocades fatbergs cagebird fireboats filecard
>   focaliser flatbeds ascribed fireblast firebolts filabegs factored
>   factories ribcages golfcart factorise leafbird lifeboats carbolise
>   fragilest birdcage geofacts fibrosed bacteroid giftable decalogist
>   cagebirds filecards bifocals focalised trifocals cabriolets fasciolet
>   forcible dogfaces bacteroids carbolised isografted boldface birdcages
>   golfcarts leafbirds factorised clofibrate clofibrates tailors saltier
>   retails toilers isolate slatier realist loiters estriol dilates
>   astride goriest dilater tirades trailed dialers aigrets goitres
>   details glister derails goiters sortied ligates roisted steroid
>   delator tierods aiglets storage gloater storied roasted glories
>   gaiters disrate gristle leotard redials gaolers goalies gelatos
>   editors reloads triages astroid dilator ordeals bristol betoils
>   rebaits celosia bolters largest coalise regilds geoidal reblast
>   dotages barites lactose laciest reboast borates dogears reboils
>   coalite stoical aridest recital triable stagier orbital loaders
>   godlier coaster locates clarets godetia recoals raciest recoats
>   blaster recoils cartels roadies astilbe albites dialogs article
>   gloried castile blister bloater lobster trilobe scalier ligated
>   colters gloated baiters escolar libator scarlet libates erotics
>   riblets boaster bristle erotica boilers aloetic scoriae elogist
>   elastic calorie bolster coalers soldier rosalic boaters solacer
>   scrotal cristae eclairs coalier dacites obliger obliges solaced
>   batoids located cotidal lobated bestrid corsage decrial tribals
>   sorbate lifters libated oracles sorbite labored delicts deltaic
>   orbited blasted radicel deorbit dialect radices bloated radicle
>   stabler directs disable coasted sidecar sidebar disrobe boasted
>   bedirts drastic goblets alecost gliders girdles scolder bolides
>   gilders giblets reblogs fairest falters borages lodgers bedlars
>   citadel reclads gastric reclogs ceroids garlics brailed strobed
>   braised catelog filters castled redacts refloat tabloid broiled
>   carotid caroled aborted forties floater florets florist loftier
>   foister folates bedrail debtors albedos foliate cagiest scribal
>   calibre caliber cradles foliage decalog foisted trifles abridge
>   cargoes loafers airbeds obliged cablers ascribe cordial floated
>   bigoted frosted refolds reflogs flirted reflags cordate oracled
>   defrost bridles coldest garbles bridals strobic trefoil baldest
>   coedits fedoras citable blastic cladist stifler gerbils aerobic
>   cobalts sarcode credits abiders boldest glacier stabled gracile
>   bodegas globate seabird driblet ragbolt forages golfers scribed
>   bodices factors stifled codgers fardels iceboat fibrate fibrose
>   fibster bridges cordage firedog garbled dogcart brigade frolics
>   defrags froglet frigate friable fragile decarbs trifled forgets
>   folders foraged trifold decabit badgers filabeg filbert ribcage
>   selfact bifolds brocade scarfed scabrid bracted grafted barcode
>   belfast catbird baldric sofabed fidgets flatbed fridges carbide
>   bifocal geofact forbids forbade fatberg bedfast crafted fabrics
>   dogface

Have fun!

Comment: Is there a specific piece of advice you are looking for? Because otherwise, this is way too broad.

Comment: IMHO This isn't “opinion-based”, but it is too broad:  there are too many possible answers given the conditions.  To @nickcarraway — if you want to begin a catalogue of these phrases, then I suggest you post it somewhere better suited to such things.

Comment: @nickcarraway A point system is a good objective way to select a "best" answer (though here the bonus categories—money, life, romance, etc.—are perhaps too subjective). But with nothing to limit submission length, answers can be made arbitrarily longer for increased score by expressing a simple idea in excess verbosity under the guise of getting the best "translation" into permissible words. There'd be no end to that. Also, the subject matter is way too unconfined. This would end up being a collection of leetspeek adages, and collection questions are out of scope on pretty much every SE site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

> EA7 600D F00D. 11FE 15 A F1E1D 0F 612EA7 1DEA5 (Eat good food. Life is a field of great ideas)

Comment: Wow!!! Way better than I could've done!

Answer (score 8):

Lack of an "N" for "not" is limiting, so these are a little tortured.

> D0 2 0DE125 A5 0DE125 D0 2 DEE (Do to others as others do to thee - do unto others as you would have them do unto you)

And another

> BAD 2 EA7 D EE110 1CE (Bad to eat the yellow ice - don't eat the yellow snow)

And another

> 11FE 15 11CE A B0C5 0F C0C0A 712EA75 (Life is like a box of cocoa treats - life is like a box of chocolates)

And another

> 1EAF D EA127 BE77E12 (Leaf the Earth better - leave the world a better place for your having been in it)

Courtesy of Wil Wheaton

> BAD 2 BE A D1C (Bad to be a dick - don't be a dick)

And finally, one that works as is

> B 600D (be good) or D0 600D (do good)

PS to add a 50 pointer:

> 612EED 15 600D (Greed is good).